# Could I use the same schema.prisma file in two separate servers to generate the same Prisma client?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, nestjs, prisma

I want to use Prisma to read and write to my db from an API server. But I also want to have a separate stand alone node server that only writes to my db and doesn't expose any endpoints.
Is this possible to do with Prisma? All the docs I've seen, you have to declare your schema in the schema.prisma, run a migration to update the db and then generate a Prisma client. I want to do all that from my API server and only want to write from my stand alone server without having to duplicate anything. Ideally would just be able to generate the Prisma client and start using it in the stand alone server.

Thanks for the help!

Ive updated my API server to have the necessary db connection using Prisma but dont have a great idea of how to generate the client from my stand alone server.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [tutorial](https://isidoro-ferreiro.medium.com/share-your-prisma-client-across-projects-44d1c7aca6fd) and [repository](https://github.com/igolka97/shared-prisma-client-example) for an example on how to generate a shared prisma client. I created a `packages` npm workspace in the `api` repo and publish the client to a private registry from there to be used in other projects.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587